# How can I fix Google PageSpeed issues with G+ code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Google PageSpeed is currently telling me I should fix an issue which it turns out refers to an iframe inserted by the PlusOne code.

The detail:
"Size content to viewport
The page content is too wide for the viewport, forcing the user to scroll horizontally. Size the page content to the viewport to provide a better user experience. 
... 
The element  falls outside the viewport."

Comment: How can you fix third party code? Well, you can't :) You could file a bug report with Google. It would be helpful though if you included the code that's causing the problem in your question. What 'PlusOne code'?